When is a submodule trivial?
I am a beginner concerning module theory, but I need it for my PhD. Sorry for obvious questions therefore.
Given a left $C(G)$-module $(V, \tilde{\rho})$ where $C(G)$ denotes the group algebra over a group $G$, so $C(G)$ consists of the sum of group elements $\sum_G \alpha_i g_i$ and $$\tilde{\rho}: C(G)\rightarrow \mathrm{End}(V)$$ as $$\sum_G \alpha_i g_i\rightarrow \sum_G \alpha_i \pi(g_i)$$
where $\pi(g_i)$ denotes an adjoint unitary conjugation representation, so in other words $\pi(g_i)(v)=U_i v U_i^\dagger$.
Given a direct sum of $V_1 \oplus V_2 =V$ such that both, $V_1$, $V_2$ are submodules. Now, what I need is to find unitary adjoint representations $\pi(g_i)$ such that the ring $R\subset \mathrm{End}(V)$ induced by $\tilde{\rho}$ maps $V_1$ to the multiplicative identity, namely $\tilde{\rho}(v)=\mathrm{Id}_\cdot, v\in V_1$, which is just the identity matrix, and on $V_2$, I want $\tilde{\rho}(v)=0, v\in V_2$.
If important: the space I am looking at is $V=\mathfrak{gl}$ and $\mathfrak{gl}=\mathds{C}\mathrm{Id}\oplus \mathfrak{sl}$, where $R$ acts like $\tilde{\rho}:\mathfrak{sl}\rightarrow 0$.
Is there references you could refer me to where conditions on rings in modules are defined? I am sure this could also be restated in a representation theoretical problem, but I have not found any.
Don't know where to look, there are thousand books and all are too theoretical and too little with practical examples like this I am afraid.

I'm sorry, I find it really hard to make sense of your posts. You're given $V$, and define $\pi$ in terms of it. But then you need to find $\pi$? And then you want to map $V_1$ to the multiplicative identity? Of what? Where does the zero element go?
